# how to create virtual network interface with different gateway

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have 2 routers and 2 different internet connections. I want to send http traffic to router 1 and everything else to router 2.

Is there something that will let me set gateway per application ?.

Also i found this application forcebindip. That will force all trafic from application (like firefox) to one network interface.
http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/

That is great. But for this to work i would have to have 2 hardware interfaces.

Is it posible to create like 2 virtualinterfaces that will connect to the one hardware interface but one will have gateway 192.168.1.1 and second 192.168.1.2

windows 7 pro

Comment: You don't need to have 2 hardware interfaces. Just add two IP to your only interface. That's as easy as `ip address add A.A.A.A/A dev eth0 && ip address add B.B.B.B/B dev eth0`. Then you need policy routing to be able to use two gateway at the same time. After that you can use `forcebindip` like you want.

Comment: im using windows 7 pro. in windows i can add 2 ip adresses to single interface and add 2 gateways. but to order gateway priority i can use numbers not ports. and i do not know can i link ip adress to gateway.